# Identifying wordpress shortcodes using a regular expression

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, shortcode

I have a wordpress shortcode which contains some other shortcodes inside it. When the first shortcode is executed i want to filter out other shortcodes using a regex.

```
[main_code]
   [sub_code id='testid']test content[/sub_code]
   [sub_code id='testid' name='testname']test content[/sub_code]
[/main_code]
```

When i execute the main_code i  want to filter the sub_code into an array and access its attributes without executing sub_code as a shortcode.

Anyone who has knowledge to give me a solution is highly appriciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to match the inner parts, then I'd advise:

```
preg_match_all('~\[sub_code([^\[\]]*)]([^\[\]]+)\[/sub_code]~', $content, $result);
```

The `[^\[\]]` matches any content without square brackets. So it's ensured no other shortcodes can exist within.

Comment: I tried your code and it gives an array with 2 empty elements. I have to consider about the attributes when matching as well

Comment: Added another placeholder for the params.

Comment: It is almost perfect. now the attributes are received as [1] => Array
        (
            [0] =>  id='testid'
            [1] =>  id='testid' name='teddsstname'
            [2] =>  id='testid' name='testname'
        )  Have you got any suggestions on getting the attributes seperately one by one

Comment: `strtr` for changing spaces into `&` ampersands. And `parse_str` for separating them, then `trim` for removing quotes. -- Alternatively a regex for that task.

Comment: what happens if i have spaces on attribute values when using this method

Comment: That wouldn't be an option then. Use another `preg_match_all()`.

Comment: What are the codez you ask? Well, `/(\w+)='([^']*)'/` might do.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5186/discussion-between-rakhitha-nimesh-and-mario)

Comment: Can u explain this /(\w+)='([^'])*'/ code. I really like to learn to write regex but it's very difficult to understand