# Matching wordpress shortcodes inside a given string

Tags: regex, string, wordpress, shortcode

I wanted to match shortcodes inside a string and found the following regex from here. It works fine. But i want to learn how it works.

Can anyone plz explain me the components of this regex and how it matches the shortcode.

```
preg_match_all('%(?<=\[shortcode\]).*?(?=\[/shortcode\])%s',$content, $result, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Identifying wordpress shortcodes using a regular expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8207098/identifying-wordpress-shortcodes-using-a-regular-expression)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are [tools to explain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/772594/regular-expression-explained-with-words) regular expressions.

Yours for example:

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?<=                     look behind to see if there is:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \[                       '['
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    shortcode                'shortcode'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \]                       ']'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-behind
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  .*?                      any character  (0 or more times
                           (matching the least amount possible)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \[                       '['
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    /shortcode               '/shortcode'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \]                       ']'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Read more about the assertions on http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html